# How to recover data I lost while installing Ubuntu 18.01?

Tags: data-recovery

While installing Ubuntu 18.01 I lost all the data in my hard disk. Previously the system was dual booted with Ubuntu 16.01 and Windows 10.

Is there is any possibility to recover my data? If so kindly suggest the way to do it.

Comment: There is a very good lesson here about complete backups of both OS before upgrading either.

Comment: There is no such version as 16.01 or 18.01.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Could you please [edit] your question to include the output of `sudo lsblk -f`? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First make sure that you don't damage the data any further by using the system on it - so turn of your PC and either find another PC or another disk to run the system on, and with enough space to recover your data.

Next you read the tutorials for [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk). This program can be used to recover data from NTFS drives. If you are lucky, most of your data is still there.